# Fastboot command with visal sturdio

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, command, fastboot

Fastboot' `getvar all` return to richtext.

This is my code:

```cs
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = "fastboot.exe";

p.StartInfo.Arguments = "getvar all";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
p.Start();
StreamReader d = p.StandardOutput;
richTextBox1.Text = d.ReadToEnd();
richTextBox1.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

However, the richtext is always empty.

Comment: use full pathname of the executable "fastboot.exe".  Also read StandardError to get error message.

Comment: the fastboot.exe file in the same project name direct .. and the command fastboot devices it working and returned data .... but getvar all not

Comment: If you run from a cmd.exe does it return results?

Comment: if you mean the command prompt .. yes return

Comment: .ReadToEnd will read everything "currently" in the stream, this may or may not be the whole output.  Move the `WaitForExit` to just after `p.Start` and see what happens.

Comment: same problem and hanging .... if i type fastboot devices its oky and show result but if type getvar all hanging and no results

Comment: What does standard error shows from your application? Are you running from VS?  If so you do not have Admin privilege in VS unless you start by right click and select Run As Admin.

Comment: yes runing with vs ... and olso the code "devices" it returned result

Answer (score 0):

Need File Fastboot.exe

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.FileName = "fastboot.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "reboot";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();


StreamReader readerStdError1 = process.StandardError;
StreamReader readerStdOutput1 = process.StandardError;

output1 = readerStdError1.ReadToEnd() + readerStdOutput1.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(output1);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**